# TPL Data flow - usage with events stream

Tags: c#, producer-consumer, dataflow, tpl-dataflow

In my application I have tons of events coming from 3rd party almost every time, I've to **process** them and **send** (publish) them over the network to the organization's RabbitMQ. My doubt is regarding usage here in TPL Dataflow. imagine the code is as below:

```
 private TransformBlock<QuoteEvent, Quote> _quotesProcessingBlock;

    private ActionBlock<Quote> _deliveryBlock;
    public TplDataFlow()
    {
        _quotesProcessingBlock = new TransformBlock<QuoteEvent, Quote>(
            x => ProcessQuoteEvent(x));
        _deliveryBlock = new ActionBlock<Quote>(quote => Publish(quote));

        _quotesProcessingBlock.LinkTo(
            _deliveryBlock,
             new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true }
            ); 
    }

    //This callback method registered at the 3rd party events producer.
//It runs single threaded, so I need to process it quickly  
    private void ProcessEvent(QuoteEvent quoteEvent)
    {
        _quotesProcessingBlock.Post(quoteEvent);

        //What will be the trigger for those lines?? 
        _quotesProcessingBlock.Complete();
        _deliveryBlock.Completion.ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
```

I'm not sure when I'll use the `_quotesProcessingBlock.Complete();` and  `_deliveryBlock.Completion`. It seems to me not reasonable to do that for every quote event (hundreds per second),

> If so should I remove it or should I move it to the other level?

Or,

> Dataflow isn't the right solution here?
>
> If so there is a alternative solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would call `Complete` when you are done with that dataflow block. In this case, when there are no more events to process. It's possible that you may do this only once when your application is shutting down, or maybe not at all.

You should `await` the `Completion` property at some point, even if you never call `Complete`; that will notify your code if the dataflow mesh fails.

Comment: As I understand your answer, I've to remove the `Complete` and `Completion` linens so it will looks like  `public void ProcessEvent(QuoteEvent quoteEvent)
        {
            _quotesProcessingBlock.Post(quoteEvent);
        }` In my case when the code is synchronous, where is the right place to `await` or to block by `GetResult()` the `Completion`?